# How can I Mock node-rest-client request?

Tags: node.js, sinon-chai, node-rest-client

I'm using node-rest-client for my project and I've come to the point where I want to start unit testing my classes that utilize [node-rest-client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-rest-client). Is there any examples on how I can **mock** the Client in my tests? I am using [Sinon](http://sinonjs.org/) in my unit testing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Step 1: In the js code you are testing, export the node-rest-client instance so it can be available to your test code. For example in myApp.js, I put this:

```
var Client = require('node-rest-client').Client;
var restClient = new Client();
exports.restClient = restClient; //instance now available outside this module

restClient.get(someUrl, ...); //actual node rest client call
```

Step 2: In your test code, create a wrapper function that returns a fake function, and use sinon to mock it into your target code. This allows you to inject the return data and response code during your test setup.

```
var nodeRestGet = function (data, statusCode) {
  return function (url, cb) {
    cb(data, { statusCode: statusCode || 200 });
  }
};

sinon.stub(myApp.restClient, 'get').callsFake(nodeRestGet("", 200));
```

Step 3: Write your test code. Note that you might want to restore the method (remove the mock) if you are running multiple tests:

```
myApp.doThings(); // TEST

myApp.restClient.get.restore(); // removes the mock
```

Comment: Thanks @JohnW, I am getting **cb** is not a function error, can you please help me on this.

Comment: @Praveen without seeing your code, it sounds like the problem is your target code that you are testing. Where I put the ellipses above in restClient.get(someUrl, ...) you need to supply a callback function as the second parameter. If you share your code I can give you a more definitive answer.

Comment: Working fine with following change. `var nodeRestGet = function (data, statusCode) {
            return function (url, opts, next) {
                next(data, {statusCode: statusCode || 200});
                return {
                    on: () => {
                    }
                };
            };
        };`